# Why are chars that start with capital letter sorted before those that start with lower letter?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sorting, sql-order-by, ascii

I am doing some basic sorting in **SQL** and I learnt this long time ago: *Names that start with capital letters are sorted before names that start with lower letter*. Example:

```
sqlite> create table letters (letter text);
sqlite> insert into letters values ('A');
sqlite> insert into letters values ('C');
sqlite> insert into letters values ('b');
sqlite> insert into letters values ('d');

sqlite> select * from letters order by letter asc;
```

OUTPUT:

```
A
C
b
d
```

In that case, we would instead need to type: `sqlite> select * from letters order by letter collate nocase asc;`, which would give an expected output of:

```
A
b
C
d
```

But my question is why is it sorted that way? I tried finding an answer, but I failed. My only guess is that ASCII as **"A"=65**, while **"a"=97**. *65<97*, meaning `"A"` gets stored before `"a"`. Does OS really work this way or there is something else I am missing? How does it even work behind the curtain?

Comment: You could specify the nocase collation for the column.

Comment: Did you read entire question? :) I did that and it works. My question is why is it stored that way and not how to do it.

Comment: Your guess is correct.

Comment: _Names that start with capital letters are sorted before names that start with lower letter._ is sometimes true, sometimes false.

Comment: Does the OS work this way? That's not relevant, it's the Sqlite engine that determines behaviour here. Why does it do that?Because that's often what's needed, and a default behaviour is required. How does it work behind the curtain? Search `collation sequences` *(it's far broader than just "that's the ascii order")*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How Sqlite3 chooses a comparison function for sorting and comparing strings is described in the [data types documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collating_sequences).

Basically, if you don't explicitly declare one with the `COLLATE` keyword in an expression or relevant column definition, it uses the `BINARY` collation mode, which acts as if the C `memcmp()` function is used to compare values - which looks at individual bytes for the first one that differs.

Sqlite stores text values using Unicode (Using either UTF-8 or UTF-16, see [`PRAGMA encoding`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding)). The first 127 codepoints of Unicode are the same as ASCII, so upper case English letters, with their lower values, will sort before lower case ones in the `BINARY` collation.

Annoyingly, this means that the same data can be sorted in different ways depending on the underlying encoding:

```sql
$ sqlite3 test1.db
sqlite> PRAGMA encoding='UTF-16LE';
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test(word TEXT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES ('A'), ('a'), ('B'), ('b'), (char(0x1F355));
sqlite> SELECT word, hex(word), unicode(word) FROM test ORDER BY word;
word  hex(word)  unicode(word)
----  ---------  -------------
     3CD855DF   127829       
A     4100       65           
B     4200       66           
a     6100       97           
b     6200       98
sqlite> .quit
$ sqlite3 test2.db
sqlite> PRAGMA encoding='UTF-16BE';
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test(word TEXT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES ('A'), ('a'), ('B'), ('b'), (char(0x1F355));
sqlite> SELECT word, hex(word), unicode(word) FROM test ORDER BY word;
word  hex(word)  unicode(word)
----  ---------  -------------
A     0041       65           
B     0042       66           
a     0061       97           
b     0062       98           
     D83CDF55   127829
sqlite> .quit
$ sqlite3 test3.db
sqlite> PRAGMA encoding='UTF-8';
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test(word TEXT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES ('A'), ('a'), ('B'), ('b'), (char(0x1F355));
sqlite> SELECT word, hex(word), unicode(word) FROM test ORDER BY word;
word  hex(word)  unicode(word)
----  ---------  -------------
A     41         65           
B     42         66           
a     61         97           
b     62         98           
     F09F8D95   127829
```

Comment: I have a sqlite3 extension that extends the standard [ICU extension](https://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/dir?ci=tip&name=ext/icu) to provide significantly improved support for working with Unicode strings, including a collation that sorts by codepoints, not raw bytes, which avoids the sorting issues shown here. If anyone's interested, let me know.